# Github actions and badges show percentage data

Tags: github, github-actions

I have read about the way to create and add a [custom workflow badge](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-a-workflow#adding-a-workflow-status-badge-to-your-repository) which will show whether the workflow passes or fails. But here's a question. Is it possible to output some percentage data on the badge and how to output this data?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about your use case. My understanding is that workflows can either fail or be successful. There are no other states or progress values that I'm aware of.

Comment: The badge github provides only shows success/failure given a complete workflow file - there is no way to show anything else on it, because that's just what it provides. You probably mean badges like codecov that are provided under the [shields.io/category/coverage](https://shields.io/category/coverage). If your coverage service happens to be among them you can just use their badge. If you have written a custom workflow for coverage, you'll have to either

Comment: 1) wait until github actions provides its own way to to get coverage badges (similar to what [gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/settings.html#test-coverage-report-badge) does), or 2) [ask shields.io](https://github.com/badges/shields/issues/new?labels=service-badge&template=3_Badge_request.md) to provide a badge given your toolchain and hope someone will write it, or 3) propose and write it yourself

Comment: @Arne Thanks for your comment. It covers the whole question I asked. Please collect them into an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @peterevans To not to ignore your comment I tried to show some code coverage badge with some percent information on it but it seems there's no way to do that without using other tools than github provided badges. Anyway, thanks for your cooment

Comment: I added it, and I'll try to keep an eye on if github gets around to add custom badges to finish it to an answer with an actual solution =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the time of writing, there is no badge provided by github to show amount of code coverage, which is the most popular percentage-showing badge. Other CI/CD frameworks usually provide such a badge, most notably and comparably [gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/settings.html#test-coverage-report-badge), and it is very likely that something like that will arrive at some point in the ongoing github actions beta.

If you can't wait that long, one other option you have is to use an external badge service. A very popular one that contains [a wide range of coverage badges](https://shields.io/category/coverage) is shields.io, they might already support the toolchain you're using.

If that is not the case, you can also [request a github actions coverage badge](https://github.com/badges/shields/issues/new?labels=service-badge&template=3_Badge_request.md) from them or even [implement it yourself](https://github.com/badges/shields/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md).

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I have seen a way of achieving that, but it's a bit like cheating. All you need is to configure a `github` action dumping the data you want into your `gist` in a format that the badge service (e.g. `shields`) [supports.](https://shields.io/endpoint) and then use the service to provide a badge based on your gist content.